# i can't pass a json object from my php to my jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I tried to pass a json object from my test.php to my jquery in index.html but i can't.
here is my test.php script:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["view"]))
{
  $output .= '
  <li><a href="#" class="text-bold text-italic">No Notification Found</a></li>
  ';
  $total_row=2;

 $data = array(
   'notification'   => $output,
   'unseen_notification' => $total_row
  );


 echo json_encode($data);
}
?>
```

and here is my jquery script , "the alert in js show undefined as result":

```
function load_unseen_notification(view = '')
 { 

  $.ajax({
   url:"test.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{view:view},
   dataType:"json",
   complete:function(data)
   {
    alert(data.notification);
    $('.dropdown-menu').html(data.notification);

    if(data.unseen_notification > 0)
    {
     $('.count').html(data.unseen_notification);
    }
   }
  })
 }
```

Comment: Where is your js `success` method?? Thats a clue by the way https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: `complete` doesn't receive data. (also, there's no such thing as a JSON object)

Comment: with success:function(data) the alert(data.notification); is not  executed

Comment: i changed this instruction "alert(data.notification);" by this     "var data1=JSON.stringify(data);
alert(data1);"         and the alert shows   {"readyState":4,"responseText":"???{\"notification\":\"<li><a href=\\\"#\\\" class=\\\"text-bold text-italic\\\">No Notification Found<\\\/a><\\\/li>",\"unseen_notification\":2}","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}

Answer (score 3):

In PHP, you need to put a **header response** from the server so that the browser knows what it got in response (see: https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml , http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

In JavaScript, you need to use **`success`** event:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
        view: 10
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data.notification);
    }
});
```

- **`success`** - A function to be called if the request succeeds.
  Arguments: `( Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )`.
- **`complete`** - A function to be called when the request finishes (after success and error callbacks are executed). 
  Arguments: `( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus )`

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

If to use **`complete`**, then access to data can be got by means of **`jqXHR Object`** (see: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR):

```
complete: function(jqXHR) {
    if (typeof jqXHR.responseJSON !== 'undefined') {
        alert(jqXHR.responseJSON.notification);
    }
}
```

Of course if necessary it is possible to combine different event handlers.

*P.S. For debugging use **`console.log(data)`** instead of **`alert(data)`** and look through the log in the browser. For example, for Google Chorme (F12, Tab: Logs): https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/get-started*

Comment: @devattitude,

Check, the object with which keys you return:
    `success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }`

or:
    `complete: function(jqXHR) {
    if (typeof jqXHR.responseJSON !== 'undefined') {
        console.log(jqXHR.responseJSON);
    }
}`

Comment: @barth thx again, see bellow my answer. first case it didn't access to console.log.. instructioon and second case : undefined

 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'notification' of undefined
    at Object.complete ((index):1235)
    at i (jquery-2.2.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith (jquery-2.2.1.min.js:2)
    at z (jquery-2.2.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-2.2.1.min.js:4)

Comment: @devattitude
I can not comment on your answer, I do not have this right.
You need to **check that PHP returns the correct data**.
It is necessary to **check exactly the `data` with all the keys received from PHP**, not `data.notification`.

Comment: i didi this in jquery: console.log(data.responseText);
  var test = JSON.parse(data.responseText);   and here is the console output:  {"notification":"\n  <li><a href=\"#\" class=\"text-bold text-italic\">No Notification Found<\/a><\/li>\n  ","unseen_notification":2}
VM42926:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.complete ((index):1235)
    at i (jquery-2.2.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith (jquery-2.2.1.min.js:2)
    at z (jquery-2.2.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-2.2.1.min.js:4)

Comment: @Dygnus, Thanks for addition about header. I have added to the answer your addition, for full completion.

@devattitude, Set the header and you can use `data.responseText` instead of `JSON.parse($.trim(data.responseText))`.

Comment: @barth I set the header in php but it dosn't work the solution for me was using the trim function. (a space caracter was added automatically i don't know why)

Answer (score 1):

It might be a good idea as well to set the content-type header at the top of your PHP script:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

jQuery will probably interpret the body as JSON instead of 'text'.

Answer (score 0):

I added $.trim()to my data.responseText and finally it's working (i don't know why :) )

```
var obj = JSON.parse($.trim(data.responseText));
$('.dropdown-menu').html(obj.notification);
```

Thx a lot for you all for your assisting